# Alternate geodesic completions of a Schwarzschild black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, topology

The [Kruskal-Szekeres solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates) extends the exterior Schwarzschild solution *maximally*, so that every geodesic not contacting a curvature singularity can be extended arbitrarily far in either direction.

Wikipedia says it is the unique maximal extension that is an analytic, simply connected vacuum solution.

So what happens without "simply"? I.e. anyone know a maximal extension that is an analytic, connected vacuum solution, but is not *simply* connected?

Comment: My guess is that the reason people specify *simply connected* in the context of analytic extensions is to avoid situations like the following: you can embed Minkowski space as a patch in all sorts of tori - just wrap the various dimensions.  So these tori are analytic extensions of Minkowski space, and I guess the "simply connected" criterion is to avoid a plethora of extensions like this.

Comment: The non-simplyconnected ones should come as quotions of the simplyconnected one by discrete groups.

Comment: Oh, is that all it is? It makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @twistor59 I keep seeing this on the unanswered list, someone want to make an "official" answer?

Comment: @MBN (apparently I can't ping two at once... ping)

Comment: I think MBN's response is more elegant than mine!

Comment: If you want an actual answer, so that you can accept it, I think you should convince twistor59 to write something up. I for one would enjoy reading it.